# AES128-ECB under UWP

Tags: c#, encryption, aes, uwp, ecb

I need help in retrieving AES128-EBC encrypted string under Universal Windows Application.
I have a password in string that is used as a key. With it's 32 bits length MD5 hash value I would like to encrypt text with AES128-EBC. 
Now I am using this for creating MD5Hash:

```
public string GetMD5Hash(String strMsg)
{
    string strAlgName = HashAlgorithmNames.Md5;
    IBuffer buffUtf8Msg = CryptographicBuffer.ConvertStringToBinary(strMsg, BinaryStringEncoding.Utf8);

    HashAlgorithmProvider objAlgProv = HashAlgorithmProvider.OpenAlgorithm
    string strAlgNameUsed = objAlgProv.AlgorithmName;

    IBuffer buffHash = objAlgProv.HashData(buffUtf8Msg);

    if (buffHash.Length != objAlgProv.HashLength)
    {
        throw new Exception("There was an error creating the hash");
    }

    string hex = CryptographicBuffer.EncodeToHexString(buffHash);

    return hex;
}
```

And this code for encryption:

```
public string Encrypt(string input, string pass)
{
    SymmetricKeyAlgorithmProvider provider = SymmetricKeyAlgorithmProvider.OpenAlgorithm(SymmetricAlgorithmNames.AesEcbPkcs7);
    CryptographicKey key;

    string encrypted = "";

    byte[] keyhash = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(GetMD5Hash(pass));
    key = provider.CreateSymmetricKey(CryptographicBuffer.CreateFromByteArray(keyhash));

    IBuffer data = CryptographicBuffer.CreateFromByteArray(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(input));
    encrypted = CryptographicBuffer.EncodeToBase64String(CryptographicEngine.Encrypt(key, data, null));

    return encrypted;
}
```

The cause why I am using `SymmetricAlgorithmNames.AesEcbPkcs7` is when I am using `SymmetricAlgorithmNames.AesEcb` the output string is empty. I don't understand why.
My question is: Does my code create an AES128-ECB encryption? Because I not really sure it does. Because the software that is waiting for that encrypted data not recognizes it, so it cannot decrypt it.

Comment: If you need security: 1. Do not use ECB mode, it too is insecure, see [ECB mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Electronic_Codebook_.28ECB.29), scroll down to the Penguin. Use CBC mode with a random iv, prepend it to the encrypted data.
2. Do not use MD5 to derive the encryption key, Iterate over an HMAC with a random salt for about a 100ms duration (the salt needs to be saved with the hash). Use functions such as password_hash, PBKDF2, Bcrypt and similar functions. The point is to make the attacker spend a lot of time finding passwords by brute force.

Comment: @zaph unfortunately there are even IETF standards depending on ECB or other UWP missing pieces. You cannot always use another.

Comment: @LexLi Sure but there a lot of usage without any reason other than some same code a developer runs across. IOW, one needs a wee understood reason to use ECB mode. Here we also have am MD5 hash for used for password key derivation so I am assuming, possibly incorrectly, that ECB mode is used without good reason or understanding.

Comment: I know that there are always better solutions how to make something more secure. Unfortunately the software that needs encrypted data using aes128ecb with md5 hash as key. And I am not sure is the code upper doing what I need.

Answer (score 0):

> My question is: Does my code create an AES128-ECB encryption? Because I not really sure it does. Because the software that is waiting for that encrypted data not recognizes it, so it cannot decrypt it.

Yes, your code create an AES encryption with ECB cipher mode and PKCS7 padding. If I correctly understand your problem, you said this works with `AesEcbPkcs7`, but failed using `AesEcb`, your software for decryption doesn't work for this.

The difference between `AesEcbPkcs7` and `AesEcb` is, `AesEcbPkcs7` use PKCS#7 block padding modes, and PKCS #7 algorithms automatically pads the message to an appropriate length, so you don’t need to pad the cipher to a multiple of the block-size of the algorithm you are using. So if you insist to use `AesEcb` to encrypt, I recommend to use `AesEcbPkcs7, otherwise an exception: The supplied user buffer is not valid for the requested operation.

So I guess, one possibility here in your decryption software, it may have the ability to use `AesEcbPkcs7`, but it doesn't implement the decrytion of `AesEcb`. Here I tested decryption based on your code, this code can decrypt `AesEcb` correctly:

```
public string Decrypt(string input, string pass)
{
    var keyHash = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(GetMD5Hash(pass));

    // Create a buffer that contains the encoded message to be decrypted.
    IBuffer toDecryptBuffer = CryptographicBuffer.DecodeFromBase64String(input);

    // Open a symmetric algorithm provider for the specified algorithm.
    SymmetricKeyAlgorithmProvider aes = SymmetricKeyAlgorithmProvider.OpenAlgorithm(SymmetricAlgorithmNames.AesEcb);

    // Create a symmetric key.
    var symetricKey = aes.CreateSymmetricKey(keyHash.AsBuffer());

    var buffDecrypted = CryptographicEngine.Decrypt(symetricKey, toDecryptBuffer, null);

    string strDecrypted = CryptographicBuffer.ConvertBinaryToString(BinaryStringEncoding.Utf8, buffDecrypted);

    return strDecrypted;
}
```

Another possibility I think you catch the exception when using `AesEcb` and the user buffer is not valid for the requested operation and handled it when you call your `Encrypt(string input, string pass)` method, the encryption failed actually.